# How to add object to scene?

Tags: three.js

I have code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init()
        {
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(0, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 100, 100);
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(1000, 1000);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var sphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(150);
            var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555 });
            var sphere_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, material1);

            scene.add(sphere_mesh);


            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

and i can't add a sphere into the scene. The only thing that i get is black square. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some fast tips:

-Place the camera to see the object, not just position but the direction where it is facing, do you have all your objects in front?

-Make the object visible, choose a good material definition, start with a boiler plate/[hello world](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene) scene, once it works, modify it to get the scene as you want it to be.